# Why my Variable richtigeHoeren only counts until 10?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have programmed an array which contains 15 Words. Now i wanna compare it with another array which contains the right words. Whenever a word is correkt i want increase my variable (richtigeHoeren). But when i type all the correct 15 words in my array the variable only counts until 10..

I dont know why, i hope you understand my question.

```
for(int k=0; k<begriffLoesungHoeren.size(); k++){

        // Get the user input

        String eintragung = begriffEintragungHoeren.get(k);

        if(eintragung!=null){
          // Compare user input with solution , if solution is right increase richtigeHoeren and jump to first for loop.

          if(eintragung.equals(loesung)){

            richtigeHoeren++;
            break;

          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare each element of the first list with each element of the second list, you should use the correct bounds:

```
for(int i = 0; i < begriffLoesungHoeren.size(); i++) {
    String loesung = begriffLoesungHoeren.get(i);
    for(int k = 0; k < begriffEintragungHoeren.size(); k++) {
        String eintragung = begriffEintragungHoeren.get(k);
        ...
```

Comment: maybe even use foreach lopos since indexes are not being used...

Comment: Okay i try it , thank you :)

Comment: I changed it , but it still counts only until 10...                    for(String loesung : begriffLoesungHoeren){
            for(String eintragung : begriffEintragungHoeren){
                if(eintragung!=null){
                    if(eintragung.equals(loesung)){
                        richtigeHoeren++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }